# How to update interval dynamically when using setTimeOut?

Tags: jquery

I want to close the popup after 5 seconds. Then how can I update the `setTimeOut` interval dynamically (or on click function)?

```
var myWindow = window.open("", "myWindow", "width=200, height=100");
myWindow.document.write("<p>This is 'myWindow'</p>");
setTimeout(function(){ 
  myWindow.close() 
}, 3000);
```

Comment: Given that the timeout will already have fired (and only ever does so once) what effect are you expecting changing the interval to have?

Comment: As per the requirement, i have to close that popup after 5 seconds or after 10 seconds dynamically change the intervals.

Comment: The requirement makes no sense. `i have to close that popup after 5 seconds` great, your code does this, although after 3 seconds. `or after 10 seconds dynamically change the intervals` this makes no sense for the reason I mentioned in my first comment

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan I think I must be missing something here. The requirement is to close the popup after _either_ 5 seconds or 10 seconds, based on some event like a user click.

Comment: @ChrisHG possible, but that's not what the OP is asking. If that is the goal, you cannot change the delay of a timeout once its created. You need to clear it and create a new one.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan IMO the intent of the OP was clear - clearing the timeout and creating a new one has the effect of changing the time at which the callback function is fired. What's the real-world difference between changing the delay of a timeout and cancelling/creating a new one?

Comment: Depends on the intent of changing the delay. Eg. if you are 4 seconds in to a 5 second timer and want to **update** the value to 10 seconds, the remaining time will be 6 seconds. However as we need to clear the existing timer and create a new one, the remaining time will be 10 seconds. It's the lack of useful detail in the question which makes it hard to answer with any accuracy.

Comment: Also, just for reference, none of the downvotes on this question are mine.

Answer (score 0):

As i understand it you want to start a timeout, and if the user interacts somehow during that time, extend that timeout to 10 seconds.

You can't change a running timeout, but you can stop it and restart it with a new delay.

If you save the elapsed time since the first start of the timeout, you can calculate the new delay to add up to 10 seconds overall.

In my example if you press `start` once it will run for 5 seconds. If you press it again during the 5 seconds, it will restart the timeout with the appropriate delay so it adds up to 10 seconds overall

```js
let timeout = null;
let timestamp = null;
$('#start').click(function() {
  let time = 5000;
  if (timestamp === null) {
    // save the current timestap 
    timestamp = +new Date;
  } else {
    // subtract the elapsed time since `timestamp` from the desired 10 seconds and restart the timer
    time = 10000 - ((+new Date) - timestamp);
    timestamp = null;
    $('#start').prop('disabled', true);
  }
  
  out(`timeout started with ${time} ms`);
  clearTimeout(timeout);
  timeout = setTimeout(function() {
    timestamp = null;
    out('done');
    $('#start').prop('disabled', false);
  }, time);
});

function out(text) {
  $('#output').append(text + '<br/>');
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<button id="start">start timeout</button><br/>
<div id="output"></div>
```

Answer (score -1):

`setTimeout` returns a timeout ID. You can store this ID to a variable and use [ClearTimeout](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/clearTimeout) to cancel the timeout and set a new one.